# Joomla article exporting to excel

Tags: excel, joomla

A bit more info on what we are trying to achieve.

We have had reports written in PHP that will create a table on the screen and then if they select the Excel radio button and rerun the report it will output the table to Excel simply by outputting the following headers before outputting the table
    header("Content-Type:  application/x-msexcel"); 
    header("Expires: 0"); 
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=discussion.xls");

When we have tried to reproduce the same report inside a Joomla article the report works fine but when we then try to output the report to Excel it does create an excel file but seems to output the whole page content and not just the table from the report (hope that makes sense)

You can see the link at http://commculturecommunity.cloudaccess.net if you select test1 it will create the Excel output but when you open it you can see the test data but can also see the rest of the page content.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks
Richard

================================================================================

We have created an article in Joomla and have embedded this code (using sourcerer) as part of the article.

```
{source}
<?php
$filename ="excelreport.xls";
$contents ="testdata1 \t testdata2 \t testdata3 \t \n";
header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
echo $contents;
?>
{/source}
```

When we go to the page an Excel file is downloaded but when we open it in Excel it has included the whole form and not just the test data created above.

Any help would really be appreciated

Thanks
Richard

Comment: Not clear about what's happening...Do you have a sample link to try

Comment: Excel's format is binary, not an open text format, so you can't just create it as easily as that; like VampiRUS says, you need to use a library that has backwards-engineered the format. Alternatively, you could output a CSV file; that IS an open, textual format which is easy to work with, and absolutely trivial if you use php's csv functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [phpExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) to create excel file with article content

Comment: Thanks VampiRuS Thanks for pointing us to phpExcel this is a much better solution as we now generate Excel .xls files and now use it for all our exporting reports.